# How do you programmatically add UI / view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm trying to load a ViewController when a UIView is tapped, but I keep getting an error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'CameraVC3''

I think it's something with not properly adding the ViewController to my storyboard, so I've tried to do it programmatically, but it's still not being recognized.

ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

    let rect1 = CGRectMake(100, 60, 40, 60)
    let captureButton2 = UIView(frame: rect1)
    captureButton2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    scrollView.addSubview(captureButton2)
    captureButton2.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
       action: Selector("didTapImageView:")))

    func didTapImageView(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer){

         let captureDetails = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CameraVC3")! as! CameraVC3
         presentViewController(captureDetails, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

CameraViewController

```
class CameraVC3: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println("camera vc3 view will appear")
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "capture:"))
}

func capture() {
     if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Another way to handle all this is with segues. Connect the view controllers in the interface builder and name the segues. Then you can use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueName", sender: self)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `UIStoryboard`'s `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method, you must have set a view controller's identifier to match the string you're passing as the identifier.

View controllers on the storyboard can have their identifiers set from the identity inspector (the same place you set the custom class for the view controller):

[image]

In the box for "Storyboard ID", just fill in a string you want to use as this view controller's identity.  In this case, put `CameraVC3` in that box.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! But how do you add multiple View Controllers? Once I change the `Class` box from `ViewController` to `CameraVC3`, my application no longer loads `ViewController` and it stops on the loading screen.

Comment: There's only 1, my main View Controller, which I think is the problem.

Comment: Yes.  So drag another one on from the object library: http://i.imgur.com/tHBQdct.png

Comment: You should not be changing the class, you should change the unique identifier. And you likely want more than one view controller defined in your storyboard.

Comment: Awesome! So I added a CameraVC3 view controller to my Main.storyboard. But I'm still getting the same error `Storyboard  doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'CameraVC3''`. 

Are there additional steps I need to take to add the View Controller to my storyboard?

Comment: Is the way I just dragged my viewcontroller onto my storyboard equivalent to writing this? 1) Create new storyboard `var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))`, then  2) add VC to storyboard just created

`vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CameraVC") as CameraVC3`

Comment: No, it's not.  There's not really any equivalence... and there's not an easy way to explain it in StackExchange comments.

Comment: OK, if you can recommend any resources to learn, that'd be awesome (right now I've been reading through the Stanford iOS course and raywenderlich's stuff). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ray Wenderlich should have good storyboard tutorials.  I'd work through those.

Answer (score 1):

With the line:

```
let captureDetails = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CameraVC3")! as! CameraVC3
```

You need to give your ViewController in storyboard an identifier name "CameraVC3". You can set this in the identity inspector, in the field `Storyboard ID`.